# django - if instance == 'userabc':

Tags: django

I have the following receiver attached to a create user:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_root_list(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    queryset = WidgetList.objects.first()
    if queryset:
        if created:
            print instance
            if instance == 'userabc':
                WidgetList.objects.create(owner=instance, name='Master List', description='Application Master List')
            else:
                WidgetList.objects.create(owner=instance, name='user root', parent=1) # Create General User List
    else:
        if created:
            WidgetList.objects.create(owner=instance, name='Anonymous', description='Dummy List for NULL access to Anonymous')
```

the `print instance` returns `userabc` but when it goes in the query the `if instance == 'userabc'` is being skipped and the query on `else` is being run.

Comment: The values on both sides of the `==` must have the same type to be equal. The type of `instance` is not string. Instead you can compare `str(instance) == 'userabc'`

Comment: Don't use str()... compare the name to the string at least. If you ever override the string representation, your code would break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print something, Python calls its string representation, which in this case is "userabc". But that doesn't make the instance actually equal to that value: obviously it's not, it's a model instance not a string. You should compare the model attribute that is being used to generate the strong representation.